# Как могу получить элемент объекта в php

Tags: php

У меня в база данных есть вот такая таблица

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [product] => 114
            [keys] => 123456
            [exist] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [product] => 21
            [keys] => 78776773
            [exist] => 1
        )

)
```

никак не могу получить элемент product

Comment: а как пытались получить??

Comment: $db_product_id-> product;

Comment: что такое `$db_product_id` ?

Comment: $db_product_id = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM product_keys WHERE product');

Comment: называйте переменные корректно, иначе они не отражают суть того, что в них хранится. в целом, если  это коллекция, то как обратиться к одному из элементов я написал в ответе....если ко всем - то нужен цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте индекс оборачивать в фигурные скобки:

```
$data->{0}->product
```

Хотя это вроде обычный массив и должно работать:

```
$data[0]->product
```

Если нужно ко всем обратиться - то нужен обычный цикл

Comment: это пример выдает ошибка синтаксиса

Comment: .........какую?

Comment: ругается на фигурные скобки

Comment: а, да, там стрелка должна быть.....исправил

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: ошибка пропала но product не вводит

Comment: покажи код как выводишь

Comment: print_r($db_product_id->{0}->product);

Comment: а если просто как к массиву `$db_product_id[0]->product`?

Comment: да, так вводит)

Comment: спасибо огромное)